# How to add a background image for ActionBar?

Tags: android, android-3.0-honeycomb

Is there any good tutorial how to add background image for ActionBar?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
myActionBar.setBackgroundDrawable()
```

Also, check out the Android Developers [Styling the ActionBar](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html#Style)

Comment: +1 for the link... You saved my day!!!